# mysql not working on xammp

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

please help me ....whenever i start xammp server and trying to start mysql It gives an error 
like...

```
4:42:52 PM [mysql] Problem detected!
4:42:52 PM [mysql] Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL"!
4:42:52 PM [mysql] MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
4:42:52 PM [mysql] You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
4:42:52 PM [mysql] or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

Comment: Probably the server is running. Is there any process in the task manager whic called mysqld?

Answer (score 0):

In a command shell, run:

```
netstat -b -p TCP
```

and look for a line that says localhost:3306 in the second column. Below this is the application's name using the port.

Answer (score 0):

U probably have an application using the same port, if you have skype(mine was) you should consider turning off the automatically start on it to free the port. Run `services.msc` to check.